# How would you interpret the solution when the word "within" is used in a contextual inequality?

Tags: inequality, terminology

How would you interpret the solution when the word "within" is used in a contextual inequality problem such as "*Each bag of sugar must be within $5$ grams of the advertised $1000$ grams.*"?

Would $995$ and $1005$ be included in the solutions?

In other words, which inequality is correct?

$|x - 1000|<5$ or $|x - 1000|\le 5$

Answer (score 1):

The lax inequality $\le $ is correct. This makes sense because then "within $1$" is still worth saying.

See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63307/57024